# How do I get an IFrame to take up the entire width using jQuery Mobile on an iPad?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using the jQuery Mobile library. I am displaying an IFrame as shown:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="600" frameborder="0" title="Content" src="https://c.na6.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=00P8000500D26o6EAB" name="docframe" id="docframe"></iframe>
```

Viewing on a desktop browser the iFrame takes up the entire width as I would hope. On an iPad the iFrame appears to take up approximately 50% of the available room. The iFrame does not appear to be contained within anything that would limit its size to 50% (i.e. it does not appear to be in a grid etc...)

What types of things should I be trying to get my iFrame to be full width?

Comment: Have you already made sure your body and html tags are full width as well?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative which may help:

```
   <head>
       <script type="text/javascript">
       function jqUpdateSize(){
            // Aspect ratio of the video's height and width. For eg: 360/480 
            var aspect_ratio = <height of the video>/<width of the video>;
            // Get the dimensions of the content div
            var width = $('#iframes-div-container').width();
            var height = width * aspect_ratio;

            $('#video-iframe').css("width",width);
            $('#video-iframe').css("height",height);
        };
        $(document).ready(jqUpdateSize);    // When the page first loads
        $(window).resize(jqUpdateSize);     // If the browser's size changes
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div data-role='page'>
     .
     .
     <your code>
     .
     .
     <div data-role="content" id="iframes-div-container">
        <center>
          <iframe id="video-iframe" src="https://c.na6.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=00P8000500D26o6EAB" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </center>
     </div> 

    </div>
    </body>
```

hope this helps.